# How to make proper Spring boot testing with embedded db mocking, AWS, with profiles, in the newest Spring version?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, embedded-database, spring-profiles

I have a Spring Boot Application which runs in AWS environment. Database is Postgres, all the environmental variables are outsourced, so I have an `application.yml` with different profiles and they read env variables like:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        initial-size: 5
        url: ${MYAPI_DB_HOST}
        username: ${MYAPI_DB_USER}
        validation-query: SELECT 1
```

I would like to create an embedded database to test all the APIs, including SQL queries. I followed this [leveluplunch](https://github.com/leveluplunch/022-preload-database-execute-sql-spring-testing) guide.

Unfortunately STS has crossed out

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
```

as deprecated. Spring documentation recommended [here](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4) to use different annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

I ran JUnit and I got an error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'kmsEncryptionConfiguration': (.....) nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'aws.region' in string value "#{T(com.amazonaws.regions.Regions).fromName('${aws.region}')}"

It is quite surprising as I wrote all the necessary parameters to Run Configurations / Spring Boot and It worked in all other cases (simple running and unit tests on non-DB-dependent functions). If I replace @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) with @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class), the result is the same. Finally I commented out both and then KMS error did not show up any more BUT other problems faded in:

I tried two different cases. First one calls an existing API which answers static values, pulled from application.yml (app version, db schemaname). I had exactly the same in another test file for controller tests and working well. Second one is a classical jdbc query as it is in the leveluplunch
guide.

```
MyProperties appProp = globalController.getMyProperties();
List<Map<String, Object>> resultSet = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = 1");
```

From the stacktrace it came out that appProp was Null and the query had a NullPointerException. For me it seems that env data is not even read from application.yml but I do not understand why. Is the annotation bad? How can I find any proper text about how to do it well which does not show me another deprecated old stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a basic example on testing Spring Boot API with H2. It is connected to a Postgres db. On maven install it would not call the default profile from application.yml but the test profile, creates a H2 database, inserts table, inserts records, runs tests on them.

I hope it will help other Spring developers.

https://github.com/somahargitai/H2test